# How to prevent a method call, when that's not exist

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my object init, I am calling the methods with their names. But some time, those methods may not declared or I don't want to call them. in case of that chance, how to prevent my method from call?

here is my calling approach : `this[collectionName]();` - here the name is parameter I receive. so the method is declared within object.

here is full code :

```
init: function( collectionName, size ){

            if( (typeof this[collectionName] ) === undefined ) return; //but not works!!!

            this.collectionName = collectionName;
            this.size =  size.toUpperCase() == "SMALL"  ? 20 : size.toUpperCase() == "MEDIUM" ? 35 : lsize.toUpperCase() == "LARGE" ? 50 : "SMALL";

            this[collectionName]();//some time method will not exist. how to check the existence and prevent it from call?
            return this.generateRecords();

        }
```

I am getting an error when the method is not their then :

```
New-DataModels.js?bust=1491457640410:69 Uncaught TypeError: this[collectionName] is not a function
```

Comment: You can check `this[collectionName]` exista and is a function

Comment: if (typeof this[collectionName] === "function") ?

Comment: better check for (typeof this[collectionName] === "function")

Comment: that's what I have written a condition, but not working for me. see my commet

Answer (score 2):

A variables does exist and is declared, because it wouldn't enter function if it didn't exist because of this:

```
// it must be === "undefined" (in quotes) actually, not === undefined
if( (typeof this[collectionName] ) === "undefined" ) return;
```

However, as mentionted in error, the problem is that

> `this[collectionName]` is not a function

i.e. `this[collectionName]` does exist, but it is not a function, and thereby you cannot call it.

You can change your function to make sure that `this[collectionName]` is a function:

```
init: function( collectionName, size ){
    if (typeof this[collectionName] !== 'function') return;

    this.collectionName = collectionName;
    this.size =  size.toUpperCase() == "SMALL"  ? 20 : size.toUpperCase() == "MEDIUM" ? 35 : lsize.toUpperCase() == "LARGE" ? 50 : "SMALL";

    this[collectionName]();//some time method will not exist. how to check the existence and prevent it from call?
    return this.generateRecords();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You almost got it, just need a small modification in checking the `typeof` your property. `typeof` returns a string indicating the type of that object.

```
if( (typeof this[collectionName] ) === 'undefined' ) return;
// notice how I made 'undefined' into a string
```

Although I think it would be better if you check if its not a function:

```
if (typeof this[collectionName] !== 'function') return;
```